# docusign mass user update - How to

Tags: docusignapi, insert-update, email-address

We have a user base of over 600 users.  Our domain email address is changing, and we need a method to update all user's email addresses.  Having the users do this would create a Help Desk support nightmare.  Are there any scripted/automated methods for accomplishing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SAML 2 SSO` then automatically when user's SAML will come to DocuSign with new email Address, then email address will be updated in DocuSign. But if you are not using SSO, then you need to contact DS Customer support and they will be able to help you in changing the email addresses of the users.